# DocuSign Envelope lock API issue

Tags: api, docusignapi

I’m using the rest api to create an envelope, and then configure it using the api sender view call (`/restapi/v2/accounts//envelopes//views/sender`) to get the DocuSign UI. Creating the envelope and viewing it the first time using sender view to bring up the docusign api works fine.

The problem occurs if instead of sending the envelope I click ‘save as draft’. When I try to go back to the envelope and view it again using sender view I get the following error with http status of 400:

```
{ 
"errorCode": "EDIT_LOCK_ENVELOPE_LOCKED",
"message": "The envelope is locked. The lock must be released before requesting the sender token for envelope, id = xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx." 
}
```

The lock seems to wear off after time (apprx 20 mins). However after it wears off I can only view the item once, and then the lock is reapplied. This error only happens on my demo account but not on production, so it seems like it's an account setting, but I can't figure out what/where the setting is.

Comment: I have escalated this to our internal engineering team.

Comment: This is stale. Look at the year.

Answer (score 1):

We have a bug logged on our side where Save Draft isn't correctly
releasing the lock on the envelope.  We should have a fix for this issue
in our DEMO environment soon. The locking feature is currently only "ON"
in our DEMO environment but not in our Production environments while we
find and fix potential issues such as the one identified here.  More
information about locking is in our February service pack (PDF) release
notes available here: https://www.docusign.com/support/releases.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue today on the demo environment. Is it safe to assume this hasn't been fixed yet?

Comment: @lhan It has been years. Still relevant?